# Loading screen won't appear on device - Cocoa OS

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-simulator, loading, ipod-touch

Hey all, I've created a loading/splash screen that loads at the beginning of my app, just simply showing the company name. It works great on the simulator, but for some reason I just get a black screen when I load the game on my itouch. Any Ideas? I use the sleep(5); method of creating a loading screen.

Comment: why would you ever use `sleep` to create a loading screen? That sounds like a horrid idea.

Comment: Apparently the problem was that I followed a tutorial. In order to show an example of the working screen, the tutorial writer added sleep to show the screen longer. With my amount of loading, I didn't realize sleep was unnecessary.

Comment: Hi, yes, just show Default.png. Please don't show your loading screen any longer than that!! I hate apps that do that. The user has apps so that they can use them, not so that, as some developers think, they can look at your loading page.

Comment: I don't anymore of course: notice that this is a year old post :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call the picture "Default.png" and it will show when loading. :)

Comment: There we go! Thanks, I feel pretty stupid right now. I knew that it did it automatically, but I thought sleep would show it longer, not mess it up.

Answer (score 0):

A better idea than calling sleep would be to present your splash screen as a subview of the root view.  When you are ready to dismiss the splash screen use `CATransition` to fade out your splash screen.